# Split JSON into two individual JSON objects using Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, kylo

I have a JSON like

```
{
    "campaign_key": 316,
    "client_key": 127,
    "cpn_mid_counter": "24",
    "cpn_name": "Bopal",
    "cpn_status": "Active",
    "clt_name": "Bopal Ventures",
    "clt_status": "Active"
}
```

**Expected output**

1st JSON :

```
{
    "campaign_key": 316,
    "client_key": 127,
    "cpn_mid_counter": "24",
    "cpn_name": "Bopal",
    "cpn_status": "Active"
}
```

2nd JSON:

```
{
    "clt_name": "Bopal Ventures",
    "clt_status": "Active"
}
```

How do I acheive this by using NIFI? Thanks.

Comment: Why you require 2 jsons?

Comment: I need to load my data into 2 column families in hbase.

Comment: Json Keys are same for all datas right?

Comment: Yeah they are same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Karthik,

Use `EvaluateJsonPath` processor to get those all json Values by using its keys.

Example: `$.campaign_key` for gets compaign key value and `$.clt_name` for get clt name.

Like above one you can get all jsons.

Then use ReplaceText Processor for convert single json into two jsons.

```
{"Compaign_Key":${CompaignKey},...etc}
{"Clt_name":${clt_name}}
```

It will convert single json into two jsons.

Hope this helpful and let me know if you have issues.

Answer (score 7):

You can do what 'user' had said. The not-so-good thing about that approach is, if you number of fields are increasing, then you are required to add that many JSON Path expression attributes to `EvaluateJsonPath` and subsequently add that many attributes in `ReplaceText`.

Instead what I'm proposing is, use `QueryRecord` with Record Reader set to JsonTreeReader and Record Writer set to JsonRecordSetWriter. And add two dynamic relationship properties as follows:

```
json1 : SELECT campaign_key, client_key, cpn_mid_counter, cpn_name, cpn_status FROM FLOWFILE

json2 : SELECT clt_name, clt_status FROM FLOWFILE
```

This approach takes care of reading and writing the output in JSON format. Plus, if you want to add more fields, you just have add the field name in the `SQL SELECT` statement.

QueryRecord processor lets you execute SQL query against the FlowFile content. More details on this processor can be found [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html)

**Attaching screenshots**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do I need to set my AvroSchema in the convertAvroToJson Processor to register schema as I'm getting schema not found exception.

Comment: Could you please help me on configurations in Record Reader and Record Writer ?

Comment: I have created a gist. You can find that here: https://gist.github.com/zenfenan/08c8646062053d4efaab92a36bf64531

Comment: This is the template that covers my answer. Download it as an XML and upload it to NiFi as a template and you can easily view the configuration

Comment: a much better approach !!